# Store file path in database

Tags: php

I want to store file path in database. i tried it. but it's not worked.  This is my code. But it's not worked.`

```
 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "uploads/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $cat=$_POST['cat']; 
$desc=$_POST['desc'];

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
 mysql_select_db("selfie") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO image_upload (category, description,image_url) VALUES ('$cat', '$desc',".$_FILES['photo']['name'].")"); 


 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 


?>
```

Can any one help me to store file path in database

Comment: ***Notice:*** There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the filename. You should also escape all user-provided data, in case it contains special characters that will cause a SQL syntax error.

```
$filename = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['photo']['name']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO image_upload (category, description,image_url, image_path) VALUES ('$cat', '$desc','$filename', '$target')");
```

Comment: I suddenly want to upload a file named `foo'bar.jpg` :-)

Comment: Using this I can save the image name. Now I want to save image path where it was save. I mean now I save image in a folder located in my server. I want to save the path of that folder.

Comment: So add `$target` to the query.

Comment: I tried. But it's not work. I'm new for php. can you give me a example

Comment: I updated my answer. I made up the column name `image_path`, you should replace that with the actual name of the column in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO image_upload (category, description,image_url) VALUES ("'.$cat.'", "'.$desc.'","'.$_FILES['photo']['name'].'");');
```

I assuming your $cat and $desc are string type.